# Java NoClass Found Error

Tags: java, https, lang, bliki

I'm trying to use Bliki to access and parse wiki pages. 
I just downloaded the zip file and put the bliki-core-3.0.19.jar into my eclipse build path.

However, when I tried to connect using sample code. there was an error.
The sample code is here:

```
public static void test(){
    String pageName = "File:Mona Lisa.jpg";
    User user = new User("", "", "http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php");
    Connector con = new Connector();
    user = con.login(user);
    List<Page> pages = user.queryImageinfo(new String[]{pageName});
    if(pages != null)
        System.out.println(pages.size());
}
```

And I got errors as:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/httpclient/HttpMethod
at info.bliki.api.User.<init>(User.java:98)
at info.bliki.api.User.<init>(User.java:71)
at main.wiki.WikiCall.test(WikiCall.java:23)
at main.wiki.WikiCall.main(WikiCall.java:32)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethod
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 4 more
```

It seems like I'm missing the http jar for the connection, but there's no one the zip file and i thought the bliki-core.jar should contain it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: isn't `HttpMethod` from Apache Commons library?

Comment: The error was caused by "User user = new User("", "", "")"; So I suppose this is trying to make a http call?

Comment: download http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/o/Downloadorgapachecommonshttpclientjar.htm jar and add into your classpath

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with `Bliki` but from your stacktrace it looks like you are missing the `Http Client` from `Apache Commons`.

You should add the jar to your project and that should solve the problem.

Get the jar from here: http://hc.apache.org/

Answer (score 0):

This issue is that even once you have added HttpClient you will likely get other errors as the Bliki library depends on a number of 3rd party libraries.

If you are not familiar with the Maven build tool it may be worth having a look as one feature is that it will transitively resolve dependencies.

As a quick start:

In Eclipse do:

1. File > New > Other > Maven Project
2. Select the 'Create Simple Project' checkbox.
3. Enter my.bliki.project as the group id and bliki-test as the Artifact id.
4. Replace the contents of the generated pom.xml with the below.
5. Right click on the project and select 'Maven > Update project.

You now have a project with Bliki and all 3rd p;arty dependencies on the buildpath (expand the Maven Dependencies folder to see what they are).

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>my.bliki.project</groupId>
    <artifactId>bliki-test</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.bliki.wiki</groupId>
            <artifactId>bliki-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.19</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```